# Работа с Progess Bar в JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar, fxml

Есть класс и метод:

```
class Example {
    public void metod_1(){
        // for(int i; i<10;i++) цикл например;
    }
}
```

В классе `Main{}`, происходит создание окна, в котором `Button` и `ProgessBarr`.

Как в классе `Controller` реализовать `ProgressBar`, чтобы его значение изменялось в зависимости от переменной `i` из метода `metod_1` класса `Example`?

Comment: [Отметьте ответ верным, получите +2](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7025/291565)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе `javafx.concurrent.Task` есть удобный метод `updateProgress()` для отчета о прогрессе выполнения, поэтому можно сделать ваш класс `Example` его наследником:

`// Example.java:`

```
package progressbar;

import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class Example extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    public Void call() {
        metod_1();
        return null;
    }

    final int MAX_WORK = 10;

    private void metod_1() {
        updateMessage("Идет работа");
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_WORK; i++) {
            if (isCancelled()) {
                updateMessage("Работа прервана!");
                return;
            }

            System.out.print("Немного поработали. ");
            System.out.println(i + 1);
            updateProgress(i + 1, MAX_WORK);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException interrupted) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    updateMessage("Работа прервана!");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        updateMessage("Работа завершена");
    }

    protected void updateMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
        super.updateMessage(message);
    }
}
```

`// Controller.java:`

```
package progressbar;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;

public class Controller {

    public ProgressBar progressBar1;
    public Button buttonStart;
    public Button buttonStop;
    public Label labelMessage;

    private Example example;

    public void initialize() {
    }

    public void startTask(ActionEvent event) {
        if (example != null && example.isRunning()) {
            example.cancel();
        }

        example = new Example();
        Thread thread = new Thread(example);
        thread.setDaemon(true);
        thread.start();

        progressBar1.progressProperty().bind(example.progressProperty());
        labelMessage.textProperty().bind(example.messageProperty());

        buttonStart.disableProperty().bind(example.runningProperty());
        buttonStop.disableProperty().bind(example.runningProperty().not());
    }

    public void cancelTask(ActionEvent event) {
        if (example != null) example.cancel();
    }
}
```

`// sample.fxml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<VBox alignment="CENTER" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.92" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
      fx:controller="progressbar.Controller">
    <Label fx:id="labelMessage"/>
    <ProgressBar fx:id="progressBar1" progress="0.0"/>
    <HBox>
        <Button fx:id="buttonStart" onAction="#startTask" text="Поехали!"/>
        <Button fx:id="buttonStop" disable="true" onAction="#cancelTask" text="Стоп"/>
    </HBox>
</VBox>
```

`// Main.java:`

```
package progressbar;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```