# Потоки в программе

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Добрый день(Скрины в ссылках ниже),возник вопрос. Запускается приложение цепляет fxml + Controller в котором есть бесконечный цикл. Я поверхностно знаком с GUI потоком (если я не ошибаюсь он отвечает за графическое отображение). И скорее всего именно на этом потоке программа заходит в вечный цикл и на нем висит. Соответственно код ниже строки

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_css/server.fxml"));
```

и окно программы не отображается. Пытался поместить эту строку

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml_css/server.fxml"));
```

в Thread но ничего не дало.
Этот код помещал в Platform :

```
primaryStage.setTitle("Server");
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 378));
primaryStage.show();
```

но желаемого результата не получил.

Есть вариант перенести код, то есть оставить контроллер чистыми а весь код в нем кинуть в метод

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
```

ниже формирования окна, тогда по идее работать будет НО доступ к полям на форме которые созданы в контроллере будут не доступны и придется все смешивать в один метод, я все таки люблю придерживаться хоть малейшего порядка )
Да и по любому есть вариант как-то обычный поток отправить выполнять цикл, а главным запустить окно, но что-то у меня не выходит. Подскажите пожалуйста как можно решить данную проблему ?

https://ibb.co/mo7FCH

https://ibb.co/mRwmKx

Comment: гуглите Runnable. а лучше ноткажитесь от вечного цикла

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Код работы tcp-сервера следует выполнять в рабочем (фоновом) потоке.

В зависимости от того, в каком виде ваш сервер будет взаимодействовать 
с пользовательским интерфейсом, Вы можете использовать как обычный `new Thread(()->{...}).start();`, так и какой-либо класс из пакета `javafx.concurrent`.

К примеру, вариант использования `javafx.concurrent.Task` для обновления прогрессбара есть в этом ответе:
[Работа с Progess Bar в JavaFX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/810030/291565)

Answer (score 2):

Получилось решить проблему, создал левый метод и обратился к нему в другом потоке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно было просто поспать ), всем спасибо =)

Comment: вы не просто создали "левый метод", вы запустили его в другом потоке. запуск длительных, а тем более "бесконечных" задач в основном потоке приложения крайне нежелательное решение...